# SSRS IIF Filtering on Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, iif

I am working with SSRS and have a tablix that needs certain rows excluded if a value in a multi-value parameter is not selected.  For example, the multi-value parameter is 'Include Loss' and the values are 'Yes' and 'No'.

So if the user selects 'No', then I want the tablix to exclude rows where Description field is equal to the text "Loss Transaction".

I am trying to write an expression to filter on the tablix as follows, but having no luck.

```
=IIF(Parameters!IncludeLoss.Value="N", Fields!Description.Value, NOTHING)
```

and use '<>' for the 'Operator' and then:

```
="Loss Transaction"
```

I get the error 'Failed to evaluate the FilterValue of the Tablix'. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters have an implicit `AND` relationship - that is, all the conditions have to be `True` for the filter to take effect.

Accordingly, you can have two filter conditions set:

`=Parameters!IncludeLoss.Value` is equal to `N` (add a second condition)

`=Fields!Description.Value` is equal to `="Loss Transaction"`

Alternatively, for complex conditions (or conditions involving `OR` or `Null` which aren't supported in a standard filter) you can just use one condition and set that condition's expression to something more complex that evaluates to a boolean and test that against `True`. For example:

```
=Parameters!IncludeLoss.Value = "N" AND Fields!Description.Value = "Loss Transaction"
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the TRUE requirement, makes much more sense now.